# Why is my MetaMask's account address same for both Kovan and Main network?

Tags: metamask, kovan

Aren't they created randomly and separately on each network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they are using same private_key and same algorithm to derive address form the private_key, just different chain.

Comment: I see, so when i create an account on Metamask, it creates both the Kovan and Main network for me at the same time?  
Cos otherwise wouldn't there be a very slightest chance that one of them might be conflicting with another person's if it was created later.

Comment: Not really, actually. When you create an account, you actually just generate a new random private_key, and it is valid in both Main network and Kovan, and cryptography ensures that there is no conflict.

Comment: "ensures that there is no conflict" ok that totally answers it.
Thank you Daniel.